# Angular display dynamically nested list

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I'm trying to display dynamic nested list in json while using ngrx/store. The problem I guess is with recursive function. I would nest each one element on click actions. Unfortunately it works only up to 2nd level of tree. What I'm doing wrong? For example with this structure:

```
asd
    qwe
```

When I click on `asd` it should looks like that:

```
asd
    qwe
    qwe
```

Then when I click on 1st `qwe`:

```
asd
    qwe
        qwe
    qwe
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msgywe - this is what I tried already. Will be greateful for any help because I'm stucked with it almost from a month..

Comment: Did you try to make it work without using store first ? I see that you're using `category.id + 1` as new identifier, this causes multiple categories with the same identifier.

Comment: Yep i tried and it worked. Someone here recommend me to use ngrx/store but then I ran into this issue :|